# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: etc

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to run this SQL script but it keeps giving me errors.

```
DECLARE 
  JobNo user_jobs.job%TYPE;
  v_date date := to_date('20130308 050000','yyyymmdd hh24miss');
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit(
      JobNo,  --Job ID
     'begin runFlow; end;', -- Procedure to execute
     v_date, -- start running at
     'sysdate + 1' -- interval of jobs 
   );
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Searched everywhere, can't find an answer.

Comment: remove all the semi-colons (;) apart from the one after end.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Is it part of a larger script? If so, perhaps the PL/SQL block before it needs a `/` at the end. Sorry, that's all I can think of.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I did, this is what I get. 

The symbol "; was inserted before "" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 62:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
   between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_

Also it is not part of a larger script. You don't have to apologize :)

Answer (score 0):

Your block works fine if you replace the runFlow call with NULL:

```
DECLARE
  JobNo user_jobs.job%TYPE;
  v_date date := to_date('20130308 050000','yyyymmdd hh24miss');
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit(
      JobNo,  --Job ID
      'begin null; end;', -- Procedure to execute
     v_date, -- start running at
     'sysdate + 1' -- interval of jobs
   );
  COMMIT;
END;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So, if I were you, I'd look at the runFlow procedure.